# Image is not uploading from admin Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I want to upload images from admin but it is not uploading neither products nor any image in CMS page or static blocks. I have changed the permissions of all media folder to 777 then also it is not working. I also tried by clearing the cache but no use.

Comment: Any error message you are getting ?

Comment: no error message i am getting when i uploading images in cms page or in static block. and for manage products there is already this message displays-Image type and information need to be specified for each store view.

Comment: product image is also not uploading

Comment: Nothing happened when you click on 'Upload' button ... Just reload page ?

Comment: Check if you have 'wysiwyg' folder in 'media' on magento root. If it is not there, create new folder with the name and try to upload

Comment: yes when i clicked on upload button,nothing happened

Comment: yes i have a wysiwyg folder in media/ directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58531/discussion-between-tbi-and-prince-kumar).

Comment: I'm casting a vote for "unreproduceable" - if any voters see this question, please consider doing the same.

Answer (score 2):

The typical fix for this problem would be to use the "No Flash Image Uploader" extension but sadly it is no longer available.

A common cause for the upload problem is a security restriction related to differing domains.  I can recreate it by changing the base media URL in "System > Configuration > Web > Unsecure".  Please check that setting in both "Unsecure" and "Secure" sections matches the equivalent "Base URL", normally it will be "`{{unsecure_base_url}}media/`". Sometimes this gets changed for CDN use, in these cases it helps to only change the media URL for individual store scopes.